# PHP: 'Sorry, you must enter a valid username and password to log in' error appearing even though the select statement from the database is correct

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am having some problems with login validation using PHP. I am selecting the correct data from the database (have checked this using phpmyadmin) and if I echo a SELECT* the data shown is correct.

However, when I enter the correct login details, the script is skipping to the error message 'Sorry you must enter a valid username and password to log in'.

I have searched for everything I can think of to try and fix this (printing results of queries etc) but no luck. The code is below:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root', 'help_me_be_healthy')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

       //mysql_select_db('help_me_be_healthy') or die('Could not select database');

    $dbc = mysql_select_db('help_me_be_healthy', $link);
      if (!$dbc) {
        die("Database could not be selected" . mysql_error());
      }

  // Start the session
  session_start();

  // Clear the error message
  $error_msg = "";

  // If the user isn't logged in, try to log them in
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      // Connect to the database
      $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root', 'help_me_be_healthy');


      echo one;

      // Grab the user-entered log-in data
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));
      //echo $_POST ['username'];
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password']));
      //echo $_POST ['password'];



      if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        // Look up the username and password in the database

       $query = "SELECT `user_id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = SHA('$password')";
       $data= mysql_query($dbc,$query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
          // The log-in is OK so set the user ID and username session vars (and cookies), and redirect to the home page
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
          setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));    // expires in 30 days
          setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  // expires in 30 days
          $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';
          header('Location: ' . $home_url);

          echo four;
        }
        else {
          // The username/password are incorrect so set an error message
          $error_msg = 'Sorry, you must enter a valid username and password to log in.';

          echo five;
        }
      }
      else {
        // The username/password weren't entered so set an error message
        $error_msg = 'Sorry, you must enter your username and password to log in.';
      }
    }
  }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Mismatch - Log In</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Mismatch - Log In</h3>

<?php
  // If the session var is empty, show any error message and the log-in form; otherwise confirm the log-in
  if (empty($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
    echo '<p class="error">' . $error_msg . '</p>';
?>

  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Log In</legend>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id = "username" name="username" 
        value="<?php if (!empty($username)) echo $username; ?>" /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id = "password" name="password" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
  else {
    // Confirm the successful log-in
    echo('<p class="login">You are logged in as ' . $_COOKIE['username'] . '.</p>');
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Niet the Dark Absol] is correct that you cannot interchange `mysql_` and `mysqli_`.

The offending piece of code is:

```
   $query = "SELECT `user_id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = SHA('$password')";
   $data= mysql_query($dbc,$query);
```

Change `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`.

And you can remove the database connection calls above `session_start()` -- they aren't needed since you are doing a perfectly good call to `mysqli_connect()` after checking to see if the user is already logged in.

Comment: thanks @hargobind:) i removed the database connection and have changed from mysql to mysqli with no change of result...

Comment: ..."with no change of result" meaning that the login is still failing? I actually recreated your setup locally and after changing that one line, it seems to work perfectly for me.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct username and password in the database? The easiest way to ensure the password is stored correctly is to go into your database program (or console) and enter `SELECT SHA('my-plain-password');` and if it doesn't exactly match what's in the password column of the database table, then you know it's an issue with the password itself.

Comment: One thing to check is the password column in your users table -- the password is stored as an SHA key which is 40 characters long. If the column is set up to be shorter than that, then the saved value will be truncated and your password query will never match. Ideally the password column is a `char` data type of 40 characters in length.

Comment: I checked the password I am using in phpmyadmin, it is correct and returning the correct value in the database

Comment: the password field type is set to char(100)

Comment: That's your issue... `char` means "store exactly this many characters." If the number of characters is less than the column length, it will pad the data with spaces. Example if I store 4 characters in an 8 character `char`, it will save it as `abcdxxxx` (where `x` is a space). Since the number of characters from SHA() will always be 40, you can make the colum char (40) and you should be golden. Either that, or use `varchar` which means "store some arbitrary number of characters up to the specified length".

Comment: i changed this to varchar(40), the length of the hashed password, and it is still giving the same error

Comment: Try running this query and seeing what the results are: `SELECT SHA('$password') as new_pass, password as saved_pass WHERE username = 'your-username';`. Does `new_pass` match `saved_pass`?

Comment: sorry i am having a bit of trouble executing that query, do I use new_pass and saved_pass in the query?

Comment: this is what i used: SELECT SHA('thepassword') AS new_pass,
       `password` AS 'thepassword'
WHERE `username` = 'theusername'

Comment: I think this conversation is extending beyond the scope of your original question. If you feel like your original question was answered, please click the checkbox to the left of the answer (near the vote Up/Down buttons). If you still need help, feel free to email me at t7d3n4r52x@snkmail.com

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing `mysql_query` and `mysqli_num_rows`. Either use `mysql_`, OR `mysqli_`, but not both. They are NOT interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT `user_id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = SHA('$password')";
       $data= mysql_query($dbc,$query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
```

Your problem is in this area of code. Try using mysql_num_rows instead mysqli, and try to output the value of mysql_num_rows() to see if it's 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) I added       
          $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($data);  
          echo "Number of rows fetched are : ". $number_of_rows;